# Python TypeError: list indices must be integers, not type

Tags: python, list, types

Im a beginner in Python and i got a very simple exercise.
I split my Hello World project in three files.

1.run.py containing the main code.

```
run.py
--------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/python

import lib

lib.hw()
printer = lib.hw()
print(printer)
```

2.lib.py the function.

```
lib.py
--------------------------------
import data
def hw():
  return(data.messages[0])
```

3.data.py the list.

```
data.py
--------------------------------
messages = [ "Hello, World!", "It Works" ]
```

If you run run.py it will print "Hello, World!".

I want to add a way to choose which value to print out of the List. 
So i add an input promt in run.py and store that int in the variable "choice" then i want to push it to the "list indices" in file lib.py "[0]" so that i can decide which value i want to print out. Of course the way i wrote it doesn't work and its just to explain what im trying to do.

```
run.py
--------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/python
import lib

print("Enter 0 or 1 to print a Message!")
choice = int(input("Enter 0 or 1: "))

lib.hw()
printer = lib.hw()
print(printer)
```

Here i replaced the [0] with [choice].

```
lib.py
--------------------------------
import data
def hw():
  return(data.messages[choice])
```

Of course this will result in an error:

```
/functions/lib.py", line 5, in hw
    return(data.messages[choice])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not type
```

How can i solve this in the most simple way?

Comment: You're not passing `choice` to `lib.hw()`.

Comment: I really wonder how to do that.

Comment: could you put a `print(choice)` statement before `return(data.messages[choice])` and tell me what you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `choice` from `run.py` to `lib.hw()` function and also modify the `hw()` function  in `lib.py` to take a parameter `choice`

```
run.py
--------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/python
import lib

print("Enter 0 or 1 to print a Message!")
choice = int(input("Enter 0 or 1: "))

printer = lib.hw(choice)
print(printer)

lib.py
--------------------------------
import data
def hw(choice):
   return(data.messages[choice])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Deleting lib.hw() and adding choice in both files did the trick. I understand now what i didn't consider.

Comment: this looks like it will work, but do you know why the OP is getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not type` rather than `NameError: name 'choice' is not defined` (which is what i would expect). If it's defined, why is it a type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the function your choice. In python, variables are not shared over multiple files. You need to change `def hw():` to `def hw(choice):` and `printer = lib.hw()` to `printer = lib.hw(choice)`